# How do I fix my illegal offset?

Tags: php

I've been trying to make this code work, but (with my small knowledge of coding) I can't seem to. Any ideas on how to do this?

The error is as follows:

> "Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\UwAmp\www\undersokning\classes\Session.php on line 4"

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function exists($name) {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function put($name, $value) {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public static function delete($name) {
        if(self::exists($name)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$name` is a string?  You could `var_dump($name);` to confirm.

Comment: Check that self and $_SESSION are pointing where you expect.  You're *assuming* they're the same thing, and it's possible they are not.

Comment: I dont see an `isset` or `empty` function call in that code. Are you sure you have posted us he right code?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem like it is. I'll get right to it! Thank you very much Patrick, I think you just gave me the answer! :) @Patrick Q